# How to resize a JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How do I modify the size of the dialog box to be popped up when I call the `showConfirmDialog()` method of the `JOptionPane` class?

Answer (score 3):

You can create `JPanel` and override it's `getPreferredSize` method and return some desired dimension. Then add that `JPanel` to your `JOptionPane`.

Rough example:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        };

//We can use JTextArea or JLabel to display messages
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setEditable(false);
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            panel, //Here goes content
            "Here goes the title",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, // Options for JOptionPane
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); // Message type
```

Comment: How would this work if the `JOptionPane` you were using had further arguments appended (like a title, message text, custom objects for yes/no, etc)? There isn't a method signature that matches adding a new `JPanel`.

Comment: @Gorb Are you absolutely 100% sure? Check my answer again. :)